# Button value is empty when use jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i am trying to select value for the selected button like the following :

html code :

```
<div class="span3">
            <div>DEBIT/CREDIT</div>
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" id="investadjust-debitcredit-button">
                <button name="debitCredit" type="button" id="credit-button" class="btn active" value="CREDIT" >CREDIT</button>
                <button name="debitCredit" type="button" id="debi-button" class="btn" value="DEBIT" >DEBIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

javascript code :

```
$("#investadjust-debitcredit-button>.active").val()
```

but i get only `empty` when i printed the above line after selecting one button.

what could be the reason.

Comment: Try encasing your code inside `DOM Ready handler`  .. `$(function() { // your code });`

Comment: Otherwise it works perfectly fine ..http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/g6YTd/2/

Comment: If the js code appers after that html there is no reason to use document.ready

Comment: i am using backbone, i am able to get other elements value but not able to get only the above field's value.

Comment: are you sure that the value of active button is not null just when you select it?

Comment: Do you happen to have duplicate IDs somewhere? Or are misusing the "active class"?

Comment: @Hanfeng, you are right, when i select the value becomes just like this `value`

Comment: so you have to check other code, the problem is not in the jquery selector ;)

Comment: @Hanfeng, would you explain little more, i really don't get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As neo said you need to place your code in document ready function and use the class name of the button without spaces or you can add underscore between the words as well like this:

```
<button name="debitCredit" type="button" id="credit-button" class="btn_active" value="CREDIT" >CREDIT</button>
```

So, the code goes like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert("value "+$("#investadjust-debitcredit-button>.btn_active").val());
});
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

you need to place your code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// your jquery code
});
```